# Cannot use the title attribute in the side navigation list template in Oracle Apex 5.0

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, oracle-apex

I am working with Apex 5.0, I am in theme 42. I am using the Standard Page template which has the side navigation bar. This side navigation bar is using the template Side Navigation Menu. Now I copied this template and made the new version which I named Side Navigation Menu 2.0, and I set this new template to be used in place of the Side Navigation Menu in all places it is being used since you can not edit the original. I modified the JavaScript in this template to have the default layout minimized which I do not believe has an effect on my problem since it occurs with the original template as well.

Problem:

I am trying to get the hover title to appear with the list items. Now in the default template, there is a title attribute set to the substitution string #A04# for the link `<a>` element. So it is similar to this:

```
 <li data-current="true" data-id="#A01#" data-disabled="#A02#"
 data-icon="#ICON_CSS_CLASSES#"><a
 href="#LINK#" title="#A04#">#TEXT_ESC_SC#</a>
```

The problem is that when I set the A04 substitution string in the list, there is not title attribute which gets set. I changed the attribute to be included in the li element, and I am still running into the same problem.  Now, I think I have narrowed the problem down to the classes being used in the parent elements of the list, so I think I have to look into the default javavscript or css files to actually see why the title attribute is being ignored. I inspected the list element and the title doesn't even appear. Does anyone know if/where I should look at these js and css files or if I am going in a wrong direction?

Anything will be helpful, thanks. I can include screenshots or more info if needed.

The two main divs in the navigation list are:

```
Main div class = "t-Body-nav" 
Main div class = "t-TreeNav   a-TreeView"
```

Comment: Link from fac586 that I recieved: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3705593 . I don't beleive it is possible, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Customising elements within APEX 5.0 nav menu is tough, hopefully improvements come in 5.1, and/or you could put in/vote for feature request apex.oracle.com/vote

Comment: @ScottWe Thanks, I will browse the vote site. I am going to look into doing this with java-script now instead of editing the html of the template, since it seems impossible the with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. At the end of this article is a gif with the result of my solution. I will not write in detail how it works but here are two tutorials on how to do it.

1. If you want menu titles only on one page, just follow these steps:

   [First step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZx9r.png) -> In your APEX aplication go to the page where you want the function (I selected Home Page)

   [Second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vejPG.png) -> Go to the events section

   [Third step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XihOQ.png) -> Create a Dynamic Action based on images
   (you can find all scripts at the end of this article)

   And you're done it should work.
2. If you want menu titles on all pages, just follow these steps:

   [First step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J25LP.png) -> In your APEX aplication go to the Global Page

   [Second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlQSI.png) -> Go to the events section

   [Third step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB5C8.png) -> Create a Dynamic Action based on images
   (you can find all scripts at the end of this article)

   And you're done it should work on all pages.

> ```
> Scripts:
>  
> document.querySelector(".t-Body-nav");
>
> const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".a-TreeView-label");
> for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
>     name = elements[i].innerText;
>     elements[i].title = name;
> }
> ```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l35e.gif)